# translation in file frontend/base/default/template/email/productalert/stock.phtml is not working?

Tags: localisation

i am trying to translate

```
<p>  $this->__('You are receiving this notification because you subscribed to receive alerts when the following products are back in stock:') </p>
```

in `frontend/base/default/template/email/productalert/stock.phtml`. but it is not working and still in english in product alert email.

does anyone knows it?

Comment: this file (/base/default/template/email/productalert/stock.phtml.) is being passed as block argument in app\locale\"Language"\Mage_ProductAlert.csv.

Comment: What language are you trying to translate it into? Also, did you use a Magento translation pack or did you create your own?

Comment: i am trying to translate it to  Norwegian (nb_NO). that is trnslation pack i am using. thanks:)

Comment: I have the very same issue. Translation strangely only doesn't work in one locale. All others work fine. Also, if I output the string in the frontend, it is translated correctly according to the locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you try to translate the string? If it is in `locale.csv` in your theme directory it should work. If it doesn't, check for typos.

If you added your own module and added there a translation file, please check whether dev mode is on. In dev mode magento only translates string in the correct files to prevent, that you deliver modules with missing translations.

If all of this doesn't fix your problem, please hook with xdebug into your translation and have a look into `Mage::getTranslator()->getData()` there should be all strings which are translated and you can compare whether it is correct. Maybe it is prefixes with `Mage_CatalogInventory::`

Comment: Thank you very much. it is giving this error  "The language 'nb_NO' has to be added before it can be used.  in /public_html/lib/Zend/Translate/Adapter.php on line 430"
and then  "No translation for the language 'nb' available.  in /public_html/lib/Zend/Translate/Adapter.php". Could you please help me how to resolve it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i want's to explain how translation works for different locale.
Below are the sequence translation loads while rendering page.

```
1- Module translation files under app/locale/[locale]/*.xml
2- Theme translations in the translate.csv file located in the theme
locale/[locale]/ directory 
3- Translations stored in the DB table core_translate
```

So now according to above sequence check the text and you can able to resolve your issue with translation.

Comment: thanks Bijal. i have checked everything mentioned above, but still translation does not work in this file frontend/base/default/template/email/productalert/stock.phtml.

Comment: Try to clear browser cache and also magento cache, and than check